# Is "temp" a reserved system name?

Tags: command-line, vim

I was doing homework on a remote server, and I realized that I had my header and cpp files swapped. So, I wanted to change the names. I began by renaming my header file 'temp'.

Then, weird things started happening. First, header file, named "temp", disappeared. The old header, named someFile.cpp, became empty. Also, my brackets started showing up as weird lowercase å characters.

Is this an issue with VI? My machine? Is there is a way to correct the situation?

**Edit:**

My machine was running Mac OS X, the remote machine was running some other Unix or Linux variant. I think it was Red Hat or Debian.

I used mv to rename the file.

Comment: What was the exact way you did the renaming?

Comment: What is the operating system in question?

Comment: @Chris, Neal, see my edits.

Comment: What's HW? I can only think of *hardware*, which doesn't make sense in context. What filesystem are you working on (some remote filesystem presumably, given that you speak of working on remote files? Or some local filesystem that you happened to be accessing over an SSH connection?)

Comment: Homework is also hw.

Answer (score 3):

POSIX does not define any reserved *filenames* as far as I am aware. Certainly I can't think of any systems that have `temp` as a reserved filename, even outside of POSIX. As for brackets, it's more likely that your encodings don't match between the client and server (or the encoding doesn't support the character that you are trying to use).

Comment: The brackets worked before the command.

Comment: @Moshe - Even if it was, I fail to see how it would cause such an issue.

Comment: What else might have caused the problem?

Comment: @Moshe - There's not enough information to provide any meaningful speculation. Again, it's the usual sort of thing to come out of misconfigured character encodings.

Comment: Is there anyway to recover a deleted file?

Comment: @Moshe - That's outside of the remit of this question, although I would point you to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/where-do-files-go-when-the-rm-command-is-issued