# How does rm -r go about recursively removing? In what order?

Tags: rm, recursive

Is there some order of operations to `rm`? I performed `rm` on a large directory and am curious where I should look to see what might have been deleted. Does `rm` work on files first, then directories? Or is it based on some information in the inode table?

Specs: rm from GNU coreutils 8.22
system: Arch Linux running on a beagleboneblack
filesystem operating on was an external Seagate HDD (ext4) using USB 2.0.

Backstory:

I was performing some directory cleanup and performed

```
cp -r A/ B/ C/ Dest/
```

Unwittingly, I followed that up with

```
rm -r A/ B/ C/ Dest/
```

when I meant to simply perform

```
rm -r A/ B/ C/
```

I caught this and hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> before too long had passed. Specifically, it was < 3 seconds as I was using the `time` command in conjunction with `rm` & `cp`.  I went in and examined `Dest/` expecting it to be non-existent, but lo and behold it was whole and *appeared* to not be affected. This is a bit surprising as `A/` `B/` `C/` were quite small. Maybe 100–200 MB total. `Dest/` however, is just shy of 1TB. Performing an `ls` on Dest/ showed that there were both files and directories at both ends of the alphabet (e.g. `AFile.txt` .... .... `Zoo.txt`).

Did I get lucky and cancelled the `rm` before it wrought havoc on my Dest/ directory? Is `rm` really that slow (thankfully!)?

If not, how does `rm` go about recursively removing things such that I can guess what might have been lost?

I'm not really expecting to recover what I might have lost, just curious what potentially was blown away.

Comment: Related:[Where do files go when the rm command is issued?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/where-do-files-go-when-the-rm-command-is-issued)

Answer (score 36):

`rm -r` works on each of its arguments in turn. If an argument is a directory, it lists the directory (with the [`opendir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/opendir) and [`readdir`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir) functions or some equivalent method), and operates on each entry in turn. If an entry is a directory, it explores that entry recursively.

This is exactly the same method that other applications use to traverse directories recursively — `find`, `ls -Rf`, etc.

The order of traversal is unpredictable. On most filesystems, the order is reproducible as long as no file is added, removed or renamed in the directory (the order could in theory be completely random and change every time, but I can't think of a filesystem where that happens). On a few filesystems, the order can in general be deduced from the file names or from the order in which the files were created or a combination of both, but you need to know the fine details of the filesystem, and it could vary depending on the driver version. The order of traversal isn't something you can rely on.

Note that `ls` or `echo *` do sort files in lexicographic order of their names. `find` and `ls -f` do not sort.

The one thing you can rely on is that the arguments are handled in order. So if `C/` was still partially there, it would mean that `Dest/` was untouched. If `C/` is gone, you can get an idea of where files have been removed in `Dest/` by checking the directory modification times and comparing them with the time `C/` was deleted or the time the copy ended. The first file to be deleted could be a file directly in `Dest/` or somewhere deep in the hierarchy depending on whether the first entry in `Dest/` that `rm` happened to traverse was a directory or not.

The speed of `rm` is mostly a matter of how many files there are to delete. It takes a very large file to have a noticeable impact on the deletion time. The bulk of the work is deleting each directory entry in turn. The file's data isn't erased, erasing a file's content only requires to mark the blocks that it was using as free, which is relatively fast.

Comment: The `-f` option of `ls` is documented as being equivalent to `-aU`, where `-a` means list all files and `-U` means unsorted. I vaguely recall encountering a version of `ls` in which `-f` didn't work (I think it was defined to be something else) but `-aU` did.

Comment: @G-Man [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/ls.html) defines `-f` (as an [XSI extension](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/help/codes.html#XSI)); it does indeed have other effects beyond unsorted. It goes back to V7, so you'd be hard-pressed to find an implementation without it apart from, strangely, BusyBox. `-U` for just unsorted is a GNU feature, I don't think it exists anywhere else.

Comment: Gilles: [Is there a sure answer for ext4 filesystem in Ubuntu 14.04?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/192253/if-rm-dir-r-has-removed-just-partial-content-of-dir-dir1-has-it-not-removed?lq=1)

Comment: @Tim No. You can test by running `ls -U` in a directory. This is the same order that `rm -r` would work in in that directory. Note that adding or removing a file can change the order of the other files.

Comment: Thanks. (1) "adding or removing a file can change the order of the other files.", so after accidental partial removal, `ls -U` doesn't help to find out if surviving dirs are untouched? (2) -U means "list entries in directory order". Does -U means the order of directory entries in the dir?

Comment: (3) In my linked question, if `rm dir` is interrupted, and I found the content of `dir/dir1` is partially deleted, can I say other existing subdirs of `dir` are untouched? In other words, in any dir, does `rm` completely remove a subdir before removing another subdir? (Note that this is weaker than knowing the order of `rm` operating in)

Answer (score 5):

As Gilles says, you can't generally predict the order of deletions within a directory, only that the top-level directories will be processed in the order on the command line.

However, you're also guaranteed that it will delete directory hierarchies from the bottom up, because Unix only allows directories to be deleted if they're empty. So in order to delete a directory, it first has to remove everything in it. If it contains subdirectories, it has to remove their contents first, and so on.