# If "rm dir -r" has removed just partial content of dir/dir1/, has it not removed anything in dir/dir2/?

Tags: rm

If `rm dir -r` has removed just partial content of `dir/dir1/` (and I cancelled `rm`), has it not removed anything in `dir/dir2/` if `dir/dir2/` still exists and contains something? My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 and filesystem ext4.

I heard [How does rm -r go about recursively removing? In what order?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/161770/how-does-rm-r-go-about-recursively-removing-in-what-order), but can my question be answered more surely?

My OS is 64bit Ubuntu 14.04 with ext4 filesystem.

Knowing if rm completely remove a subdir before removing another subdir is weaker than knowing the order of rm operating in. So my question is not duplicate of the linked one.

Answer (score 3):

The top-voted answer (https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/161772/88983) in the question you linked to says the following:

> The order of traversal is unpredictable. (...) The order of traversal isn't something you can rely on.

So I would say you generally cannot know for sure whether `rm` deleted items in `dir/dir2`. What you *could* do, however, is run `rm` in verbose mode on a copy of your directory and see if, on your system, there seems to be some order of traversal.

Comment: Thanks. but knowing if rm completely remove a subdir before removing another subdir  is weaker than knowing the order of rm operating in.