# Would cutting & pasting a file to a USB drive be the equivalent of deleting the file?

Tags: linux, files, security, rm, usb-drive

I've always wondered if cutting & pasting / removing the file from an OS would be the equivalent of taking proper precautions when deleting a file such as using the `rm -rf` command.

I DID read here: [Where do files go when the rm command is issued?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10883/where-do-files-go-when-the-rm-command-is-issued#10884) that IF you move it via sneakernet that all the OS does is unlink the file thus rendering it useless, the same as (to my understanding) the command `rm -rf` would do.

I would just like to know, hypothetically speaking, what would be the best, most secure way of removing a file from existence? So far I can only think of shredding it via the `dd` command, shredding it via bleachbit, `rm -rf`ing it or as I'm super curious to know, using a USB flash drive to physically remove the file.

Comment: How is this question different to the one asked in your link?

Comment: Bear in mind that the `-f` and `-r` flags to `rm` don't do anything special to the contents of the file. One tells `rm` not to ask for confirmation when it might otherwise do so, and the other tells it to delete the contents of any subdirectories too.

Comment: Because while they mentioned how rm works, they didn't directly ask nor answer what happens to a file when it's removed from it's original system onto a peripheral. I'd like to know some detail as to what's left behind if anything even is left behind & if there is what can be done with that data?

Comment: And the other question's answer seems to address that quite clearly. (Last but one sentence in the answer.) Or maybe you didn't realise the same rule applies? - it does.

Comment: I guess I just wanted to know if there is anything special in a way a file is treated when moved onto a peripheral (cut/paste) vs just being removed via the rm command.

Comment: Ah ok. "No" :-)

Comment: Wow lol okay well, I just wanted to clarify that for myself, thanks roaima.

Comment: There are several programs like `shred` from GNU coreutils that can "securely" erase a file (by overwriting them once or repeatedly, with zeros or random data and/or with particular bit patterns), they aren't effective on COW filesystems like btrfs or zfs, or on journaled filesystems, etc.    `shred`'s man page includes a list of types of filesystems which it isn't effective on.