# Keep a history of all the modifications to a text file

Tags: linux, files, version-control

I have a plain text file (not containing source code). I often modify it (adding lines, editing existing lines, or any other possible modification). For any modification, I would like to **automatically** record:

- what has been modified (the diff information);
- the date and time of the modification.

(Ideally, I would also like to be able to obtain the version of my file at a specific time, but this is a plus, not essential).

This is surely possible with Git, but it's too powerful and complex. I don't want to deal with `add`, `commit` messages, `push`, etc. each time. I would simply like to edit the file with `vi` (or equivalent), save it, and automatically record the modification as above (its diff and its time).

Is there a tool to accomplish this in Linux?

---

**Update**: Thanks for all the suggestions and the several solutions that have been introduced. I have nothing against `git`, but I explicitly wished to avoid it (for several reason, last but not least the fact that I don't know it enough). The tool which is closest to the above requirements (no `git`, no commit messages, little or nothing overhead) is RCS. It is file-based and it is exactly what I was looking for. This even avoids the use of a script, provides the previous versions of the file and avoids the customization for `vi`.

---

The requirements of the question were precise; many opinions have been given, but the question is not - per se - that much opinion-based. Then, obviously, the same goal can be achieved through a tool or through a script, but this apply in many other cases as well.

Comment: In the past I would have said copyfs, and possibly closed the question as a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/996/do-we-have-an-undo-in-linux/1004#1004 . But copyfs is unmaintained and no longer present in modern distributions. So the past answers mentioning copyfs need to be updated, and this question is a good opportunity to look for a replacement.

Comment: Note that if you only ever use Vim or Emacs, they can be configured to make a backup on each save.

Comment: If you are trying to learn git, then this may be useful https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/2897/204

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' Thanks for your observations. Vim or Emacs can keep a backup of each modification, or does each time the new backup replace the previous one, so that only the last backup is available?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor The link can always be useful. What I suffer from Git is (AFAIK) that I must make several steps (add, commit, push) and I can't automate them. For a plain text file, I would like to avoid this.

Comment: Git is actually quite simple, especially for local-only use with a simple history, which is what you've described.

Comment: @BowPark Emacs (and probably Vim, I haven’t checked) can be configured to keep multiple backups of modified files. See [the Emacs wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ForceBackups) for an example.

Comment: @BowPark Any given file must only be added once, and push is only necessary if you want to keep the file history at another place as well. The use case you described only needs a commit after each edit/save.

Comment: Git is very easy to automate: https://github.com/ralfholly/git-autocommit
There also `git-annex` as a possible all-in-one solution, which encompass multiple utilities and external tools. @BowPark

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could try the venerable RCS (package "rcs") as @steeldriver mentioned, a non-modern version control system that works on a per-file basis with virtually no overhead or complication.  There are multiple ways to use it, but one possibility:

- Create an RCS subdirectory, where the version history will be stored.
- Edit your file
- Check in your changes: `ci -l -m -t- myfile`
- Repeat

If you store this text in your file:

```
$RCSfile$
$Revision$
$Date$
```

then RCS will populate those strings with information about your revision and its datestamp, once you check it in (technically, when you check it out).

The file stored in `RCS/` will be called `myfile,v` and will contain the diffs between each revision.  Of course there's more to learn about RCS.  You can look at the manpages for `ci`, `co`, `rcs`, `rcsdiff` and others.

Here's some more information:

- If you skip creating the `RCS/` directory, then the archive will appear in the same directory as your file.
- You "check in" a file with `ci` to record a version of it in the archive (the `*,v` file in the RCS/ directory).  Check-in has the weird side effect of removing your file, leaving your data only present in the `*,v` archive.  To avoid this side effect, use `-l` or `-u` with the `ci` command.
- You "check out" a file with `co` to reconstitute it from the archive.
- You "lock" a file to make it writable and prevent others from writing to it, which would create a "merge" situation.  In your case, with only one user modifying the file, "locked" means writable and "unlocked" means read-only.  If you modify and "unlocked" file (by forcing a write to it), `ci` will complain when you try to check the changes in (so, avoid doing that).
- Since you're the only one editing your file, you have a choice of scenarios: you can keep your file read-only (unlocked) or writable (locked).  I use unlocked mode for files that I don't expect to change often, as that prevents me from accidentally modifying them, because they're read-only, even for me.  I use locked mode for files that I'm actively modifying, but when I want to keep a revision history of the contents.
- Using `-l` with `ci` or `co` will lock it, leaving it writable.  Without `-l` it will be read-only with `co` or it will be removed altogether with `ci`.  Use `ci -u` to leave the file in read-only mode after checking its contents into the archive.
- Using `-m.` will prevent `ci` from asking for a revision message.
- Using `-t-` will prevent `ci` from asking for an initial message (when the archive file is first created).
- Using `-M` with `ci` or `co` will keep the timestamp of a file in sync with the timestamp of the file at the time of check-in.
- `co -r1.2 -p -q myfile` will print revision `1.2` of `myfile` to stdout.  Without the `-p` option, and assuming that `myfile` is "unlocked" (read-only), then `co -r1.2 myfile` will overwrite `myfile` with a read-only copy of revision `1.2` of `myfile`.  `-q` disables the informational messages.
- You can create "branches", with revisions like `1.3.1.1`.  I don't recommend this as it gets confusing fast.  I prefer to keep with a linear flow of revisions.

So, if you prefer to keep your file always writable, you could use `ci -l -M -m -t- myfile`.  You can use `rcsdiff myfile` to see the differences between the current contents of `myfile` and the most recent checked-in version.  You can use `rcsdiff -r1.2 -r1.4 myfile` to see the differences between revisions `1.2` and `1.4` of `myfile`.

The archive file is just a text file, whose format is documented in `man rcsfile`. However, don't attempt to edit the archive file directly. IMO, the text-based archive file, the absolute minimal extra baggage (only a single archive file), and keyword substitution are RCS's biggest strengths and what makes it a great tool for local-only, single-user, single-file-at-a-time versioning.  If I were redesigning RCS, I would remove the complications beyond this scenario (e.g. multi-user, branching), which I think are better handled by more modern distributed version control systems.

As with any command, there are some quirks; you should play around with test files until you understand the workflow you want for yourself.  Then, for best results, embed your favorite options into a script so you don't have to remember the likes of `-t-`, for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried to read `man ci` for your options, but still can't understand them very well. Could you (even briefly) explain them? And: given a specific revision of the file, how can I simply print the whole file at that point (not to modify it, but only to show it)? Something like `rcs print -r 1.2`.

Comment: Maybe it is `co -p<revision_number> myfile`.

Comment: Doesn't this answer break the requirement that the changes be recorded automatically?

Comment: One can use what i mentioned in my post, in conjunction with jrw32982's answer for recording automatically changes, namely, `inotifywatch`(from `inotify-tools`) @DavidZ As you can check for close_write event on file, and then use `ci -l -m -t- myfile`.

Comment: @NordineLotfi Yes, exactly, and if this answer had described how to use `inotifywatch` to make this process automatic, I wouldn't be commenting on it. But it doesn't.

Comment: disregard the comment i deleted, thought you meant this for my post :D @DavidZ

Comment: Use `-r1.2`, not `-r 1.2`.  Sorry for the quirk! :-)  So, `co -p -q -r1.2 myfile` to print to stdout.

Comment: Well, this brought back bad memories of just what a beast RCS was. Git seems much simpler to use.

Comment: A massive thank you @jrw32982supportsMonica for the update to your answer. I struggled to understand the locked/unlocked concept, which is now more clear.

Comment: @NordineLotfi Your suggestion is very useful. Yes, with `inotifywatch` it can be easily automatized (or with any other one-liner; it's easy to meet this requirement even if the present answer doesn't explicitly mention it).

Comment: @MichaelHampton IMO, git's complexity is way off the charts compared to RCS.  The ideas underlying git are simple enough, but the awful, inconsistent UI ruins that simplicity, turning it into an swamp of special cases.  Additionally, git is about as opaque an interface as you can get; it's very hard to know what's really going on when you run each command, and all changes to your state are binary. RCS is trying to solve a much simpler problem and, although it has its flaws and quirks, is much simpler and *much* more transparent.  I understand exactly where BowPark is coming from.

Answer (score 15):

#### Give `git` a chance

I don't see why it is an issue to use a powerful tool. Just write a simple bash script that runs `git` periodically (via `cron` or `systemd` timers); auto-generate commit messages etc.

As others highlighted in the comments it is - of course - possible to create a local repository (see [here](https://github.com/TeamFlowerPower/kb/wiki/localRepo) and [there](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/setting-up-a-repository) for more details).

> If you prefer to host your own remote repo, you'll need to set up a "Bare Repository." Both `git init` and `git clone` accept a `--bare` argument.

#### Borg backup

I can also recommend [borg backup](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). It offers you:

- Timestamps
- `borg diff` (compare between snapshots)
- Pruning (get rid of older snapshots - say you want a snapshot for the current month every day but otherwise only one per month)
- Encryption (optional)
- Compression (optional)
- and much more...

The cool thing is that it is very flexible - it is easy to setup but give you a lot of options if you want so.

I once wrote a [quick-start guide](https://github.com/TeamFlowerPower/kb/wiki/Backup-with-Borg) which might be of help.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I would really like to avoid `git`, also because I do not have a remote repository. Borg is a very interesting tool. I tried it, and checked out your guide. It seems perfectly suited for the backup of a directory with several (or thousands) of files, but not in my case. Each backup creates a different snapshot, their names must be defined each time; also, AFAIU there's no immediate way to `cat` a file inside a snapshot (the snapshot must be first mounted or extracted). Correct me if I'm wrong. It's an excellent tool, but I think it does not fit to this case.

Comment: @BowPark not that git does not require a remote repository at all. `git init` leaves you with a fully-functional , completely local repository.

Comment: Note that there is no requirement for a remote repository to exist when using git.

Comment: @Quentin @Eric I had googled several times for a only-local `git` repository, but without finding clear information. Thanks for this. My knowledge of `git` is very little, but this could be the occasion to make some practice. In the meanwhile (and for *this* specific case), I find the RCS solution more straightforward.

Comment: @BowPark, you are right you can only compare between snapshots. For one file a local `git` repository is probably best. In my automation script I enter the time and date of the snapshot.
[On the same page](https://github.com/TeamFlowerPower/kb/wiki/localRepo) you will also find a guide for creating a local `git` repository. ;-)

Comment: Yes git is local, but can synchronise to/from (push/pull) a remote.

Comment: The problem with git in not commit, than is easy. The problem starts when you want to do some thing useful. It is just too hard to use, too inconsistent, and easy to shoot your self in the foot.

Answer (score 10):

There a couple ways that you could do this:

- `vim`
- `emacs`
- `git`
- `inotify-tools`
- `git-annex` (all-in-one solution)

Which are all detailed here:

## Using Vim:

Then I'd recommend using undo history, which not only (as it's name suggest) relate to the act of `undo`ing an action in the Vim editor, but also the one you save too. More [here.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/undo.html)

Adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
let vimDir = '$HOME/.vim'
let &runtimepath.=','.vimDir

" Keep undo history across sessions by storing it in a file
if has('persistent_undo')
    let myUndoDir = expand(vimDir . '/undodir')
" Create dirs
    call system('mkdir ' . vimDir)
    call system('mkdir ' . myUndoDir)
    let &undodir = myUndoDir
    set undofile
endif
```

Will make it so every changes/undo will be permanently kept under the directory  `undodir` under your local `vimDir`, which is by default either `.vim` in your home directory, or other ones mentioned in the output of `:version` or `--version` on the commandline.

For even more control over your undo history, I'd recommend also using [Undotree](https://github.com/mbbill/undotree) to complement the experience.

## Using Emacs:

There is a similar named packages called [Undotree](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoTree), which does similar things. More information on Undo history [here](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UndoCommands).

## Using Git:

I'd recommend using [git-autocommit](https://github.com/ralfholly/git-autocommit), which is a small bash script, with git as it's only dependencies, that watch the current git directory (where you launch it) for any new files/or modified files, and commit them.

Given the nature of `Git` it keep every changes to the file, and while it wouldn't be suited for a production/serious project, it is a useful solution if you don't mind not having commit message/generic commit message (which you can always edit/add later on).

Launch it after navigating on the wanted git directory (which is first made with `git init` on a specific directory, more info on [the official manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/gittutorial)) like so:

```
screen -dmS namehere git-autocommit -i 1 -V
```

if you're using `screen`, for `tmux`:

```
tmux new -n namehere git-autocommit -i 1 -V
```

otherwise:

```
git-autocommit -i 1 -V
```

will suffice if you prefer to not background it.

## Using inotify-tools:

I'd recommend using `inotify-tools` or more specifically `inotifywatch` which can detect and (as it's name suggest) watch a file/directory for changes, which you can then do action on it (like save it somewhere else, etc).

Here the flag to use with `inotifywatch`:

```
inotifywait -r -m -q -e close_write --format %w%f yourdirectorypathhere
```

and here an example `Bash` script using the above:

```
#!/bin/bash
inotifywait -r -m -q -e close_write --format %w%f directorytowatch | while IFS= read -r file; do

    process $file
done
```

Where `process` can be anything you'd want, like `tar` if you want to make backup on file modification, or with `rclone` if you want to upload it somewhere...

## Using git-annex:

I'd recommend `git-annex` which not only encompass `Git` but many other external tools, like `inotify-tools`, `bash`, `tar`, `rclone`, `borg` etc.

More info on [here](https://git-annex.branchable.com/).

If you feel like reading the wiki/forum later on, you can also git clone it locally, for offline reading:

```
git clone git://git-annex.branchable.com
```

for the website, forum (it's all in markdown, so it's very fast to download...), and codebase (it's in Haskell!) etc

Comment: A massive thank you also for this answer, which provides so much solutions, not only for me, but for anyone else who is interested.

Answer (score 7):

Another approach, which will cover all files in a given file system, is to use a log-structured file system such as [NILFS](https://nilfs.sourceforge.io/en/).

Such file systems append changes, they don’t replace data. This is effectively equivalent to continuous snapshotting (or rather, checkpointing), and allows you to revisit the file system at various points in the past. Older checkpoints are liable to be garbage-collected once they reach a certain age, but checkpoints can be turned into permanent snapshots, and it is possible to automate that, for example to keep one snapshot per hour for the last month, then one per day for six months, then one per week etc.

NILFS is well-supported on Linux and is quite effective when used for `/home`.

Comment: +1 because this is very interesting, too. Thank you. I think it's too much in this case, but can be used in several other scenarios.

Answer (score 4):

[Gitfs](https://github.com/presslabs/gitfs/) gives the best of both worlds, at least if it works for you. It provides a view of a git repository where you can edit files and every version is committed automatically.

```
mkdir mnt
gitfs https://example.com/repo.git $PWD/mnt -o repo_path=$PWD/working_copy
```

After this, you can edit files in `mnt/current`, and every version of the files will be automatically committed to git and will also be accessible through `mnt/history/*/*`.

Note that the first argument must be a remote repository. Gitfs doesn't seem to work with a local repository: if it's bare, it instructs git to access the `origin` remote which doesn't exist, and if it's non-bare, Gitfs tries to push to it, which fails, and Gitfs won't tell you except via a debug message so you lose all your changes.

A word of caution: gitfs seems rather buggy and poorly maintained. [Silent failures](https://github.com/presslabs/gitfs/issues/294) are a common problem (pass `-o log=-,debug=true,foreground=true,…` to attempt to diagnose). You need to enable `user_allow_other` in `/etc/fuse.conf`, because the [argument manipulation is buggy](https://github.com/presslabs/gitfs/issues/258). It's the right concept, but I can't recommend it unless somebody takes up maintainership and fixes it up (I'm not volunteering).

Answer (score 3):

I used a simple Bash script, possible called `vers`. Synopsis:

1. Run my usual editor on the files passed as args. After all editing:
2. For each file, look for the highest name like `file.V[0-9][0-9]`.
3. If different checksum, `cp -p` the next higher version, and `chmod 400`.
4. If no previous version, make `file.V01`
5. Declutter any excess to a _VERSIONS subdirectory.

Helpful for establishing what you changed, and on what days.

Comment: recommend posting the bash script in question, in a code block to help even more :D.

Comment: @NordineLotfi The script got left on a client site long ago, and would probably have been careless on filenames with spaces etc. I still use the manual sequence: ls -ltr to check for next version, diff to check for unwanted debug, cp -p to record time of last update, chmod 400 to prevent execution. I started a better version, but requirements creep has got me: multi-file, cksum for changes, too many options, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a peek at [src](http://www.catb.org/%7Eesr/src/) (it stands for Simple Revision Control), a lightweight system to manage independent files (not whole projects). It is available on Debian (small wonder), or easy to install yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to create a function that does the tedious part for you ?

For exemple (note: I do *not* know git yet, so I just put "placeholder git commands" that you may way to change to make it work)

```
myvim () { vim "$@"  # put the arguments to myvim after vim (this allows you to add options, too)
           # and then the auto-commit part here. Note: I do *not* know git yet... fix where needed
           # I assume you are in the right directory for git init...
           { git init ; gid add ; git commit ;}
           # or if git add needs the names: (may want to get rid of options in args...)
           # { git init ; git add "$@" ; git commit ;}
           # or
           # { git init ; for f in "$@"; do git add "$f" ; done ; git commit ;}
}
```

You may want to replace the ";" between the commands with "&&" to ensure the next step is only done if the previous one returned 0

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that revision control is the way to go.
Yes `git` is way too complex. There are other revision control tools. The modern easy to use ones are Subversion (`svn`) and Mercurial (`hg`).

- subversion is non-distributed, non-locking, but supports locking, and has a global revision number.
- mercurial is distributed, non-locking (is like `git`, but easier to use).

Both are easy to use.

## What is hard about `git`

Many people have commented that `git` is no harder to use than other tools with respect to `init`, `add`, `commit`, and `push`. This is nearly true (except that for git to do a commit you need to do `add` then `commit` (this is a 200% of the essential effort).

The problem comes when you start doing what a revision control system is designed for. Up to this point you have gain no benefit. You are only investing in revisions, in the hope that they will be useful. In the same way that making a back up is of no benefit (restoring a backup is of benefit).

The difficulty comes with analysing history and time travelling. There are many gotchas here, and there are no good free graphical tools. `svn` and `hg` are much better behaved, have a good easy to use command line and GUI.

Comment: I don't know subversion, neither mercurial, so I can give them a look. The problem, as for Git, may be the fact that it's not possible to automate the required steps (choose a commit message each time, commit, etc.).

Comment: Git is too hard, see the comment. Mercurial works in a similar way, but is easy to use.

Comment: For local-only versioning, there's even the venerable RCS ...

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor: how is `git init`, `git add` and `git commit` *hard* to use?

Comment: I don't see a solution here to avoiding the "add", "commit", or "push" steps, which is what the question asks for. Regardless of whether or not you personally feel something is "easy to use", does it avoid those steps? If so, could you please [edit] your answer to explain?

Comment: _"Yes git is way to complex. There are other revision control tools. The modern easy to use ones are. Subversion (svn) and mercurial (hg)."_ - The basic steps that the OP needs are virtually identical in subversion, mercurial, and git. Your "git is too hard claim" seems without merit, for this situation.

Comment: @BowPark Have your bash-script-that-wraps-the-edit-with-version-control accept a message stub or just put in a (redundant) username or timestamp. "auto-saved by script" or some such.

Comment: `fossil` is another version control system, similar to `git`, `svn`, `mercurial`

Comment: @mpez0 Sorry, I can't understand your question. Can you please rephrase it?

Comment: @BowPark Your problem with git is the requirement for a check-in comment. Have the script (that does check-out, check-in, start editor, etc.) provide one.

Comment: @BowPark git can be automated: use bash scripts.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk `init`, `add` and `commit` are not hard. `add` followed by `commit` commit is one two many steps (100% more steps than needed). The real problem is when you try to do the more interesting stuff. I do wonder if most people ever get to the interesting stuff. It is just too much brain tax with git.

Answer (score 0):

?
notepad++  according to this thread, which seems semi reliable
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/notepad-edit-history/29de4e36-fd5b-48f2-8aea-b92992f9f8ba

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/441798)